# POSHGUI How to access SelectedItem/Value of a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid

I am using a SaaS called [Poshgui](https://poshgui.com/) that allows you to create WPF GUIs for the frontend and connect controls with Powershell functions as your code-behind utilizing two-way data binding.  Currently, I have a button control that when clicked fires off a powershell function, which executes a SQL query against the database to return all actively running jobs and binds that data to my DataGrid, which is also displayed in the frontend GUI.

What I would like to do is click/highlight the row in the datagrid and be able to click a separate button that will execute a powershell function using the value of the column/row the user currently has selected.  I have tried using SelectedItem/SelectedValue, but to no avail.

Here is an example of something I have tried, but unfortunately can not get the selected value back in my testing: $test = `($JobStatusDataGrid.SelectedItem).JobName`

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="332" Height="334" Margin="31,152,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding JobStatusData}" Name="JobStatusDataGrid"/>
```

[image]

Comment: of course 30 minutes after posting the question I have been stuck on for hours I figured it out.  Adding the answer now..

Answer (score 1):

```
function StartJob {
$results = New-Object 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[System.Object]'
    foreach ($object in $JobStatusDataGrid.SelectedItems)
    {
    $results.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
            "JobName" = $object.JobName
            "CurrentStatus" = $object.CurrentStatus
        }
        )
        write-host $object.JobName
    }
}
```